# sql query analysis query, how to know if an order has only 1 row

Tags: sql

HI I need to do the following and not sure how in SQL...

The table ORDER_TABLE has order#, Part#, Qty sold, order type. Each order can have multiple rows,
like many parts in an order'

I want to get the orders that had only 1 row, and that the qty was only = 1.

and the order types were in (TRP, TRY, TRI).

```
Select Order_Table where QTY = 1 and Order_TYPE in ('TRP' 'TRY' TRI')
```

How do I code for the 1 row only per order that i want?

SO I want this case:

```
Order#   Part#    QTY   ORDER_TYPE
12345    TR1      1         TRY
```

not

```
12344     TR1     1         TRP
12344     TR2     1          TRP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
select ot.order_id
from order_table ot
where Order_TYPE in ('TRP' 'TRY' TRI')
group by ot.order_id
having count(*) = 1;
```

If you need the rest of the information, you can use a `join` or similar construct to get all the values from the matching rows.

EDIT:

You seem to want the additional information.  The general SQL is:

```
select ot.*
from order_table ot join
     (select ot.ordernum
      from order_table ot
      where Order_TYPE in ('TRP' 'TRY' TRI')
      group by ot.ordernum
      having count(*) = 1
     ) ot1
     on ot.ordernum = ot1.ordernum
```